# Sencha Touch 2 cross-domain login

Tags: spring-security, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to do a cross-domain login using the Sencha Touch 2 and Spring Security ?

Comment: Can you explain little bit more about what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with Restful Web Services. You can build a restful web service with Spring, and Spring Security can handle both authentication and authorization. I believe this is the only way, since you can't redirect pages that are not in the same domain with a regular Spring Security authetication. To make the application works cross-domain, you'll need this lib http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html.